# Java RSA Encryption to file decryption error loading and saving to file

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I have been trying to solve why my piece of code to do some basic encryption isn't working. I have tested the keygenerator and using the encrypt and decrypt directly, and that seems to work fine. However if i load and save to files in the following code, it seems to give me a decryption error in my console. I cannot spot what the issue may be. I am fairly new to cryptography and Java so your assistance would be greately appreciated!

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

public class RSAwithDigitalMessage {
    public KeyPair generateKeyPair() throws Exception {
        KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        generator.initialize(2048, new SecureRandom());
        KeyPair pair = generator.generateKeyPair();

        return pair;
    }


    public String encrypt(String plainText, PublicKey publicKey) throws Exception {
        Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

        byte[] cipherText = encryptCipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes(UTF_8));

        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText);
    }

    public String decrypt(String cipherText, PrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception {
        byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherText);

        Cipher decriptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        decriptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

        return new String(decriptCipher.doFinal(bytes), UTF_8);
    }

    private void dumpKeyPair(KeyPair keyPair) {
        PublicKey pub = keyPair.getPublic();
        System.out.println("Public Key: " + getHexString(pub.getEncoded()));

        PrivateKey priv = keyPair.getPrivate();
        System.out.println("Private Key: " + getHexString(priv.getEncoded()));
    }

    public String getHexString(byte[] b) {
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            result += Integer.toString((b[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void SaveKeyPair(KeyPair keyPair, String username) throws IOException {
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
        PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
        String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");

        // Store Public Key.
        X509EncodedKeySpec x509EncodedKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(
                publicKey.getEncoded());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path + "/"+username+"_public.key");
        fos.write(x509EncodedKeySpec.getEncoded());
        fos.close();

        // Store Private Key.
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8EncodedKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(
                privateKey.getEncoded());
        fos = new FileOutputStream(path + "/"+username+"_private.key");
        fos.write(pkcs8EncodedKeySpec.getEncoded());
        fos.close();
    }

    public KeyPair LoadKeyPair(String username)
            throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidKeySpecException {
        // Read Public Key.
        String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        File filePublicKey = new File(path + "/"+username+"_public.key");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path + "/"+username+"_public.key");
        byte[] encodedPublicKey = new byte[(int) filePublicKey.length()];
        fis.read(encodedPublicKey);
        fis.close();

        // Read Private Key.
        File filePrivateKey = new File(path + "/private.key");
        fis = new FileInputStream(path + "/private.key");
        byte[] encodedPrivateKey = new byte[(int) filePrivateKey.length()];
        fis.read(encodedPrivateKey);
        fis.close();

        // Generate KeyPair.
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(
                encodedPublicKey);
        PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);

        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(
                encodedPrivateKey);
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);

        return new KeyPair(publicKey, privateKey);
    }

    public  String sign(String plainText, PrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception {
        Signature privateSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        privateSignature.initSign(privateKey);
        privateSignature.update(plainText.getBytes(UTF_8));

        byte[] signature = privateSignature.sign();

        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signature);
    }

    public boolean verify(String plainText, String signature, PublicKey publicKey) throws Exception {
        Signature publicSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        publicSignature.initVerify(publicKey);
        publicSignature.update(plainText.getBytes(UTF_8));

        byte[] signatureBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(signature);

        return publicSignature.verify(signatureBytes);
    }


}
```

**Update**: I have gotten rid of the commented code. In my actual script i call it like this for example:

```
RSAwithDigitalMessage RSAE = new RSAwithDigitalMessage();
KeyPair pair = RSAE.generateKeyPair();
String username = "Sdsdf";
RSAE.SaveKeyPair(pair, username);
KeyPair myKP = RSAE.LoadKeyPair(username);
string subject = "dfsf"
encSubject = RSAE.encrypt(subject, mykp.getPublic());
decSubject = RSAE.decrypt(encsubject,mykp.getPrivate());
console.log(decSubject)
```

This give me the error: Error in Writer--> Decryption error

Comment: can you add the actual decryption error to your question

Comment: And show what you are actually calling, at the moment everything is commented out in `main`.

Comment: @Heny I have added the updates to the file. It still isnt getting the result i need after simplifying it.

Comment: "Error in Writer--> Decryption error".What Writer? There is no Writer anywhere in your code. Post the actual exception stacktrace.